# PHP multidimensional array type hinting for function parameter

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, type-hinting

In PHP, is it possible to type hint a multidimensional array as a function parameter?

Of course you can type hint a single array as such:

```
function Example(array $parameter) {}
```

But if a function needs the parameter to be a multidimensional array is there any way to enforce this through type hinting?

Comment: PHP is not as strongly typed as Java or C#. That is why you even have concepts like `mixed` in PHP. So, PHP does not care if your array must contain only doubles or strings or `mixed` but perhaps you could implement a check *on your own* if you need that functionality. The one  way to fake it is to create a class: `DoubleArray` perhaps and then use it for Type-Hinting...

Comment: And by double do you mean multidimensional or the values are doubles (floats)?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Multidimensional Array, sorry I'll update the question to make that clear

Answer (score 1):

If by `DoubleArray` you meant an Array of Doubles (Floats) only. Then you may want to fake it using a Custom Class. Consider the Code below. Notice that the initial Array Contains `strings` but the final results doesn't:

```
<?php

    class DoubleArray{
        protected $instance;
        public function __construct(array $arrDoubles) {
            foreach($arrDoubles as $key=>$double) {
                if(!is_double($double)){
                    unset($arrDoubles[$key]);
                }
            }
            $this->instance = array_values($arrDoubles);
        }

        public function push($numDouble){
            $this->instance[] = $numDouble;
        }

        public function get(){
            return $this->instance;
        }
    }

    $arr    = array(2.35, 72.9, 88.45, 42.76, "No...", 57.77,  "String is not Double");
    $da     = new DoubleArray($arr);

    var_dump(getData($da));


    function getData(DoubleArray $data){
        // ALL ARRAY FUNCTIONS STILL APPLY TO THE $doubleArray VARIABLE
        // HOWEVER TO GET THE CUSTOM DOUBLE ARRAY DATA, YOU MAY HAVE TO
        // JUST CALL THE get() METHOD ON THE DoubleArray INSTANCE: $data
        $doubleArray    = $data->get();
        return $doubleArray;
    }

    // THE var_dump(getData($da); ABOVE PRODUCES:
    array (size=5)
      0 => float 2.35
      1 => float 72.93
      2 => float 88.45
      3 => float 42.76
      4 => float 57.77
```

> However, if by `DoubleArray` you meant `Multidimensional Arrays`, you can still fake it using a Custom Class as illustrated below.

```
<?php

    class DoubleArray{
        protected $instance;

        public function __construct(array $arrMDDoubles) {
            foreach($arrMDDoubles as $key=>$subArray) {
                if(!is_array($subArray)){
                    throw new Exception("DoubleArray accepts only Multidimensional Arrays...");
                }
            }
            $this->instance = $arrMDDoubles;
        }

        public function push($arrArray, $key=null){
            if(!is_array($arrArray)){
                throw new Exception("You can only Push an Array...");
            }
            if(!is_null($key)){
                $this->instance[$key]   = $arrArray;
            }else{
                $this->instance[]       = $arrArray;
            }
            return $this;
        }

        public function get(){
            return $this->instance;
        }
    }

    $arr    = array(array(2.35, 72.93,), array(88.45, 42.76), array("No...", 57.77,  "String is not Double"));
    $da     = new DoubleArray($arr);

    var_dump(getData($da));


    function getData(DoubleArray $data){
        // ALL ARRAY FUNCTIONS STILL APPLY TO THE $doubleArray VARIABLE
        // HOWEVER TO GET THE CUSTOM DOUBLE ARRAY DATA, YOU MAY HAVE TO
        // JUST CALL THE get() METHOD ON THE DoubleArray INSTANCE: $data
        $doubleArray    = $data->get();
        return $doubleArray;
    }

    // THIS TIME THE THE var_dump(getData($da) ABOVE WOULD THROW AN EXCEPTION
    // IF THE GIVEN ARRAY IS NOT MULTI-DIMENSIONAL BUT PRODUCE SOMETHING
    // LIKE THIS OTHERWISE:     
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => float 2.35
          1 => float 72.93
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => float 88.45
          1 => float 42.76
      2 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'No...' (length=5)
          1 => float 57.77
          2 => string 'String is not Double' (length=20)
```

Comment: Well mistakenly I meant multidimensional array, but I hadn't thought of using a class to force the parameter type, thanks!

Comment: `multidimensional-array` tag was there from the very beginning.

Comment: @revo    And yet even a Master like  AbraCadaver asked: *And by double do you mean multidimensional or the values are doubles (floats)?* Would you also let him know that, too?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by *Master* but since you were the first guy who made a certain statement about *doubles* and because original poster wasn't fast enough to reply to you, second guy who came to this question read your certain comment on *doubles* and then found no answer from original poster for the sake of clarity. So he doubted and tried to explicitly ask about it. You probably didn't care about question tags and more importantly question's requirements. Poster was clear enough about his needs by stating *Of course you can type hint a **single array** as such*.